# Simple Qt Read From Text File Program not Compiling

Tags: c++, qt

Basically I made a simple program to read a line of text but whenever I run the program I get an error of

```
no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'QFile' and 'QString')
while(file >> name >> month >> day >> year >> subject >> level >> apages >> total >> one >> two >> three >> four >> five >> six >> seven >> eight >> nine >> ten)
```

and another error of:

```
expected unqualified-id before '<<' token
         QDebug << QString(name);
```

I've been trying to find something online for an hour now but I really couldn't find anything that worked or that I could understand. I would really appreciate any input that can be provided.

relevant code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QFile>
#
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString name, month,  subject, level;
    int day, year, apages, total, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten;

    QFile file("C:/Users/brandan/Desktop/GUIPrograms/Kumon.txt");
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        return;

    while(file >> name >> month >> day >> year >> subject >> level >> apages >> total >> one >> two >> three >> four >> five >> six >> seven >> eight >> nine >> ten)
    {
        QDebug << name << month << day << year << subject << level << apages << total << one << two << three << four << five << six << seven << eight << nine << ten;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the API information of [QFile](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfile.html) it seems that you should use e.g. a `QTextStream` object to use the `<<` and `>>` operators. Regarding the debug error: `QDebug` is the name of a class, not an instance in memory. From the [QDebug](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdebug.html) page, it appears that you can use `qDebug()` instead.

Comment: @user3183403: tip #1: Blue texts are hyperlinks, clicking them will open a new page in your web browser. Tip #2: the people at QT helpfully included samples in their online help.

Answer (score 0):

`QDebug` is a type, you need to use an instance of `QDebug` which is retrieved from the function `qDebug()`:

> ```
> qDebug() << a << b << c;
> ^^^^^^^^
> ```